# Submitting empty field prompts KeyError instead of ValidationError

Tags: python, django

Original Question: Custom Form ValidationErrors render differently than those rendered by Django

Referring to the image below, I have a hard time figuring out from resources and Django's source code on why the ValidationError we raise our own (from our own cleaning/validation) are rendered differently from ValidationErrors rendered by the form (Django) itself. Field ValidationErrors raised by Django are rendered in a 'floating bubble' while ValidationErrors I raised are rendered as red text.

The method I used to raise ValidationErrors are as per Django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute), while how I render the form in the template is simply by calling `{{form}}` as provided by Django's Template engine - albeit by also using [crispy](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I've verified that it has no effect here other than styling the error message to be red in colour instead of a plain, bold black text under the field.

Ideally, I would like to know how or what I should do in order to make all ValidationError (Django's default and my own) display uniformly to prevent inconsistent design across fields in a form. Preferably, as red text. Any help I can get are much appreciated!

#### Image of the errors in the form

[image: ValidationError]

#### Forms

```py
# EXAMPLE
class AbstractUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    mail = forms.EmailField()
    mobile = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['mail', 'mobile']
    
    # validate phone number
    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        if len(mobile) < 10 or len(mobile) > 11:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Please put in a valid local phone number")
        return mobile
```

#### Template

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!-- make content override base.html's content section-->
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                    User
                </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

#### Models

```py
# EXAMPLE
class LdapUser(ldapdb.models.Model):
    # LDAP meta-data
    base_dn = settings.LDAPUSER_BASE_DN
    object_classes = ['inetOrgPerson', 'person']

    # person
    username = fields.CharField(db_column='cn', primary_key=True)
    given_name = fields.CharField(db_column='givenName')
    user_password = fields.CharField(null=True, db_column='userPassword')
    mobile = fields.CharField(db_column='mobile')

    # inetOrgPerson
    display_name = fields.CharField(db_column='displayName')
    mail = fields.CharField(db_column='mail', unique=True)
```

#### Update

As per clarification by @abdul-aziz-barkat - I did some testing by adding `novalidate` to the form tag. I've noticed that submitting the form without filling some fields work as intended (`ValidationError`s prompted as red presumably by Django's default validation) but not specifically to two fields in my form - `username` and `mail`. Leaving any of these 2 fields empty would result to `KeyError 'required'` while `DEBUG=True`

Refer image here: [image: ValidationError after adding novalidate]

The only thing that's different about the two fields as compared to others are `username` has `primary_key=True` while `mail` has `unique=True` as their parameters in `models`. My model also is an extension of [django-ldapdb](https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb) but I don't think that has any bearing to my problem here.

I've tried validating them myself but received similar result

```py
# EXAMPLE
class validate_ldap_required_fields():
    def username(username):
        if username is not None:
            True
        else:
            False

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if not validate_fields.username(username):
        raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
    return username
```

I've also tried adding `blank=False` as their parameter in models, also received similar results.

### KeyError Traceback

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://host.domain.com/user/new/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['mydjangoapp.apps.MyDjangoAppConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/vikings/vikingsldap/views.py", line 71, in dispatch
    return super(UserAccessMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 85, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 392, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 150, in clean
    self.validate(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 128, in validate
    raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')

Exception Type: KeyError at /user/new/
Exception Value: 'required'
```

Comment: Those errors in the floating bubble are not rendered by Django, that is your _browser_ performing some validation on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors in the floating bubble are not rendered by Django (Both your custom and Django's default errors would be rendered like you see with the one in red), that is your *browser* performing some validation on it's own. You can tell your browser to not perform this validation by adding the `novalidate` attribute on your form tag:

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion by adding the `novalidate` attribute in my form tag, however what this ends up doing is having no `ValidationError` raised in the form at all. Instead, it raised a `KeyError at /user/new/ 'required'` in `DEBUG=True`. Other than that, I do see that the 'floating bubble' `ValidationError` rendered in Chrome does look different when it's rendered by Firefox. Any suggestion on what next, does Django really do no validation of its own at all hence, I'd need to clean all the form fields my own like I do with `mobile`?

Comment: @IrfanHakim Django does perform validation, please add your view and the _full_ stack trace of the error to the question